# in jquery datepicker can add alt field with classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

hi I am using [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field)

in starting i set datepicker with following way

```
  $(".td-datepicker).datepicker();
```

class  .**td-datepicker** apply on four input text box and their id are following

1. #startdate
2. #enddate
3. #edit_startdate,
4. #edit_enddate

now i want to set alt field in all four input field

how can i add by class because if i add by id then repetition of code occur 
like below

```
$('#startdate').datepicker("option","altField","#alt_startdate");
$('#startdate').datepicker("option","altFormat","mm/dd/yy");
$('#enddate').datepicker("option","altField","#alt_enddate");
$('#enddate').datepicker("option","altFormat","mm/dd/yy");
$('#edit_startdate').datepicker("option","altField","#alt_edit_startdate");
$('#edit_startdate').datepicker("option","altFormat","mm/dd/yy");
$('#edit_enddate').datepicker("option","altField","#alt_edit_enddate");
$('#edit_enddate').datepicker("option","altFormat","mm/dd/yy");
```

and can i add multiple option in datepicker after initialization
like for

```
  $('#edit_enddate').datepicker("option","altField","#alt_edit_enddate");
    $('#edit_enddate').datepicker("option","altFormat","mm/dd/yy");
```

can i write code for above two line in one line . is this any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the `altFormat` on all of them, assuming they've the same format:

```
$(".td-datepicker").datepicker("option", "altFormat", "mm/dd/yy");
```

For the multiple options at once (example):

```
$(".td-datepicker").datepicker("option", { 
    disabled: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

To solve your issue, based on the ids you're using:

```
$(".td-datepicker").each(function (idx, el) { 
    $(this).datepicker("option", "altField", "#alt_" + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

If you change your mind, yes, you can use classes instead.

It's all on the API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/